# The easiest way to handle IF / OR in PHP while outputting inside HTML?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that has outputs like these:

```
$dashboard_output = '';

(if / else statements here)

$dashboard_output .= '';

(more if / else statements here)

$dashboard_output .= '';
```

An example output would be:

```
$dashboard_output .= '<div>You have '.$orders_count.' orders.</div>';
```

Now, I want to write "order" if there's 1 order and "orders" if there's multiple orders.

The way I do it now is:

```
if ($orders_count >1){
  $s = 's';
}
$dashboard_output .= '<div>You have '.$orders_count.' order'.$s.'.</div>';
```

I know, feel free to have a laugh. But is there an easier way to do this within the $dashboard_output tags? Because as far as I know I can't do an if/else within that output line.

Comment: Don't sweat about people laughing. Trust me that many people have tried to make that same sort of functionality many a times ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is strictly an if/else issue, you can use the ?

```
$dashboard_output.= '<div>You have '.$orders_count.' order'.($order_count>1 ? 's' : '').'</div>';
```

The ? is a quick way to do an if/else. It is "condition" ? "true result" : "false result".

Comment: `The ?` BTW has also a name (And no it's not *question mark*)

Comment: Yes, but even if you tell someone that it is a ternary operator, they won't remember the name. I have heard it called everything from tertiary to turdberry.

Comment: It's called the conditional operator. Ternary is just the kind of operator it is (just like a binary operator). Granted it's (probably) the only ternary operator in PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked and made a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would do it with an inline if/else statement:

```
$dashboard_output = '<div>You have '.$orders_count.' '.($orders_count >1 ? 'orders' : 'order').'.</div>';
```

Hope this helps you!